# How to change the colour of a ttk.Checkbutton when it is !disabled and selected?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

How to change the colour of the indicator of `ttk.Checkbutton` when it is `!disabled` and `selected`? The following picture shows it is blueish in colour.

[image: sample]

Typing the following:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
root = tk.Tk()
s = ttk.Style()
print(f"{s.map('TCheckbutton', 'indicatorcolor')=}")
```

returns:

```
s.map('TCheckbutton', 'indicatorcolor')=[('pressed', '#ececec'), ('!disabled', 'alternate', '#9fbdd8'), ('disabled', 'alternate', '#c0c0c0'), ('!disabled', 'selected', '#4a6984'), ('disabled', 'selected', '#a3a3a3')]
```

I tried to change `('!disabled', 'selected', '#4a6984')` to red color by using

```
s.map('TCheckbutton.indicatorcolor',
          background=[('pressed', '#ececec'),
                      ('!disabled', 'alternate', 'red'),
                      ('disabled', 'alternate', '#c0c0c0'),
                      # ('!disabled', 'selected', '#4a6984'),  # original
                      ('!disabled', 'selected', 'red'),
                      ('disabled', 'selected', '#a3a3a3')]
          )
```

and replacing the word `background` with `foreground` and even removing the word entirely but these methods failed to work. I also tried the below syntax but to no avail.

```
ss.configure("TCheckbutton.indicator.", background="red", foreground="red",
             indicatorcolor="red")
```

Comment: Not all themes support all options, have you tried different themes?

Comment: @Thingamabobs Noted but I still can't cause any color change to the indicator in any of the themes I have, i,e, `alt`, `clam`, `classic` & `default`. Maybe the indicator color can't be changed? I wonder.

Comment: Disabled is a special state, at least for Windows it should be handled by the operating system and you might not have control over the colors in this state. But I never had gone this far into styling to state it as a fact.

Comment: By the way, I'm almost positive that I had changed the indicator color of a Checkbutton in the past, just not in the disabled state. What OS your onto and are you able to change the color in normal state?

Comment: @Thingamabobs it is the `!disabled` (i.e. not disabled) and not the `disabled` state that I would like to change. Linux. Can point me to your working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me under Windows 11 and the theme `alt` the *indicatorcolor* corresponds with the `forground` option and the box of the *indicator* is colored by the *indicatorcolor*. So it might be confusing. But I think the code below should show how it is done

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style()
common_fg = 'white'
common_bg = 'black'
sel_bg = 'red'
style.theme_use('alt')
style.configure('TCheckbutton',
                focuscolor = '',
                font=['arial','10','italic'])

style.map('TCheckbutton',
          foreground = [('disabled', common_fg),
                      ('pressed', common_fg),
                      ('active', 'blue')],
##          background = [('disabled', common_bg),
##                      ('pressed', '!focus', common_bg),
##                      ('active', common_bg)],
          indicatorcolor=[('selected', 'red'),
                          ('pressed', 'pink')]
          )
c = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text='test')
c.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me the correct syntax. Works on `alt`, `classic` & `default` themes in Linux except for `clam` theme.